# AngularJS - Reload ng-style background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need to dynamically change the div's ng-style background?

*div*:

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{candidate.image}})'}">
    {{candidate.name}}
</div>
```

*controller*:

```
angular.module("MyModule")

.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.candidate = {
        "image" : "myurl.png",
        "name" : "My Name"
    };

    $scope.changeCandidate = function() {
        $scope.candidate = {
            "image" : "anotherurl.png",
            "name" : "Another Name"
        };
    };
});
```

When a button fires `changeCandidate()` function, the displayed name changed from `My Name` to `Another Name` but the background-image of ng-style remains the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/px3w7w3u/1/

When you're using ng-style use object with key value pairs and pass it.
In your case you should have something like this:

```
$scope.candidate = {
        "style" : {
            backgroundImage: "url(myurl.png)"
        },
        "name" : "My Name"
    };

$scope.changeCandidate = function() {
    $scope.candidate = {
        "style" : {
           backgroundImage: "url(anotherurl.png)"
         },
        "name" : "Another Name"
    };
};
```

Then in html:

```
<div ng-style="candidate.style">
    {{candidate.name}}
</div>
```

One thing to point out, if you need to have dashes use camel case - same as for directives and components in your case backgroundImage transforms to background-image css:

more info:

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-style.asp

Comment: Hey pegla, this worked for me. Thanks for the reference too!

Answer (score 1):

Write custom style:

```
 $scope.getStyle = function(url){
  return {
    'background-image': "url(" + url + ")",
    'background-position': 'center center'
  }      
}
```

and usage:

```
<div ng-style="getStyle(candidate.image)">
    {{candidate.name}}
</div>
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6j9uywaa/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to load the div after getting background image in your scope by using **ng-if** as shown below,

```
<div ng-if="candidate.image" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{candidate.image}})'}">
    {{candidate.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Immanuel. I keep getting the same result even with ng-if in my div.